# Xamarin SuppressLint Attribute error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to convert the suppress lint attribute in Xamarin.

I convert `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to `[SuppressLint(Value = new[] { "NewApi" })]` over my activity in c#. But when I compile I got this error and I don't know how to fix it. I google a lot but didn't find the answer:

```
error: '.class' expected
value = Mono.Cecil.CustomAttributeArgument[])
```

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to run Android Lint over the generated ACW code?

Comment: In Android/Java `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` will cause Android Lint to suppress *warnings* when using APIs that are newer than your minimum API level, this would have no effect with C#/F# code.

Comment: @SushiHangover It's for xamarin.android so it's do the same thing like it do in java. By the way, I find that it was not this line how cause the problem, it was a cas of a class in the class how have the supresslint attribute