# Xamarin SuppressLint

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Can't find info how properly use SuppressLint in Xamarin. There is just basic info on Microsoft sites. Official android documentation shows code for Java/Kotlin.

I've found this post about it, but there is no answer. And i have the same error

[The post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44055688/xamarin-suppresslint-attribute-error)

> Error     error: '.class' expected
> value = Mono.Cecil.CustomAttributeArgument[])
> 1 error

```
[SuppressLint(Value = new[] { "NewApi" })]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId) {}
```

So how do we use it in Xamarin?

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve by using this attribute?

Comment: @Jason hello, i don't understand your question. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve that requires you to use `SuppressLint`?

Comment: I don't have problems, i just want working equivalent code from Java like @SuppressLint("")

Comment: There is an existed issue on the [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15497). In addition, this class was obsoleted in xamarin.android 12 according to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.annotation.suppresslint?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12).